# Logic math with existential universal quantifications

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

hey I am taking a logic math class and I am not sure if this is vaild.  The orginal problem is

```
-ExEy [x =/= y ^ C(x,y) ^ C(y,x) ]
```

note that the - is the negation, E is existential and C(x,y) is a function/ Predicates, ^ is the and function

QUESTION: can I use De Morgan to get

```
AxAy [x=y V -C(x,y) V -C(y,x)]
```

note that A is the universal, V is the or function.

Comment: Yes I think that's just standard De Morgan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just the standard application of the De Morgan law. Both versions mean that if C(x,y) and C(y,x) then x=y.